# Docker 1.4.1 fails to start on Fedora 21: FATA[0000] EOF

Tags: docker, fedora

Recently my `docker` service on local Fedora 21 stopped working. When I try to run the daemon using:

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

It ends with:

```
Job for docker.service failed. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Checking docker status by `sudo systemctl status docker`

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since pon 2015-02-09 10:37:44 CET; 5s ago
     Docs: http://docs.docker.com
  Process: 2673 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -d $OPTIONS $DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS $DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2673 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

lut 09 10:37:44 localhost.localdomain docker[2673]: time="2015-02-09T10:37:44+01:00" level="debug" msg="Registering POST, /exec/{name:.*}/start"
lut 09 10:37:44 localhost.localdomain docker[2673]: time="2015-02-09T10:37:44+01:00" level="debug" msg="Registering DELETE, /containers/{name:.*}"
lut 09 10:37:44 localhost.localdomain docker[2673]: time="2015-02-09T10:37:44+01:00" level="debug" msg="Registering DELETE, /images/{name:.*}"
lut 09 10:37:44 localhost.localdomain docker[2673]: No sockets found
lut 09 10:37:44 localhost.localdomain docker[2673]: time="2015-02-09T10:37:44+01:00" level="info" msg="-job serveapi(fd://, tcp://0.0.0.0:2376) = ERR (1)"
lut 09 10:37:44 localhost.localdomain docker[2673]: time="2015-02-09T10:37:44+01:00" level="fatal" msg="No sockets found"
lut 09 10:37:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
lut 09 10:37:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
lut 09 10:37:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
lut 09 10:37:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
```

It turns out there is no `/var/run/docker.sock` socket, which cannot be created while starting docker service. If I try to run it with:

```
sudo docker -d
```

it ends with:

```
[1] % sudo docker -d
INFO[0000] +job serveapi(unix:///var/run/docker.sock)   
INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock) 
FATA[0000] EOF
```

Adding `-D` option:

```
[1] % sudo docker -d -D
INFO[0000] +job serveapi(unix:///var/run/docker.sock)   
INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock) 
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /version                    
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/json                
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/top   
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/logs  
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/viz                 
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/search              
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/ps              
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/json            
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/changes 
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/json  
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /_ping                      
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /events                     
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /info                       
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/{name:.*}/json      
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/get                 
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/{name:.*}/get       
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/{name:.*}/history   
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/export 
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/attach/ws 
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /exec/{id:.*}/json          
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/copy 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/exec 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /exec/{name:.*}/start      
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /exec/{name:.*}/resize     
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /commit                    
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/pause 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/resize 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/start 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/attach 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /auth                      
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/kill 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/unpause 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /images/{name:.*}/tag      
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/restart 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/stop 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/wait 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /build                     
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /images/load               
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /images/{name:.*}/push     
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /images/create             
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/create         
DEBU[0000] Registering DELETE, /containers/{name:.*}    
DEBU[0000] Registering DELETE, /images/{name:.*}        
DEBU[0000] Registering OPTIONS,                         
DEBU[0000] docker group found. gid: 977                 
DEBU[0000] Generated prefix: docker-8:3-6961299         
DEBU[0000] Checking for existence of the pool 'docker-8:3-6961299-pool' 
FATA[0000] EOF
```

It was working a few days ago, docker was always run with options:

```
--selinux-enabled -D -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 --bip=172.17.42.1/16 --dns=172.17.42.1 --dns-search=docker
```

**My question is**: what may be the source of the problem?? Docker was running smoothly a few days ago. What changed was an update of `docker-io` on 5th February according to `yum.log`:

```
[0] % sudo tail -n 100 /var/log/yum.log | grep dock
Feb 05 18:49:42 Updated: docker-io-1.4.1-8.fc21.x86_64
```

More details about my OS:

**Fedora 21** `Linux 3.18.5-201.fc21.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Feb 2 21:00:58 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

**Docker** `Docker version 1.4.1, build 5bc2ff8/1.4.1`

PS: my previous docker version was:

```
Dec 15 20:34:33 Updated: docker-io-1.4.0-1.fc21.x86_64
```

### UPDATE

It turns out that this problem is not related to `docker-1.4.1`, I have already tried downgrade to 1.4.0 and 1.3.2 with the same result. I checked on my logs and the last time it worked for sure was on February 4th. Since that time couple of packages were updated, here is the full list from yum.log:

```
Feb 05 18:49:31 Updated: claws-mail-3.11.1-3.fc21.x86_64
Feb 05 18:49:31 Updated: claws-mail-plugins-pgp-3.11.1-3.fc21.x86_64
Feb 05 18:49:31 Updated: firewalld-filesystem-0.3.13-2.fc21.noarch
Feb 05 18:49:31 Updated: 1:xscreensaver-base-5.32-4.fc21.x86_64
Feb 05 18:49:32 Installed: python2-firewall-0.3.13-2.fc21.noarch
Feb 05 18:49:32 Updated: firewalld-config-standard-0.3.13-2.fc21.noarch
Feb 05 18:49:32 Updated: firewalld-0.3.13-2.fc21.noarch
Feb 05 18:49:32 Updated: 1:xscreensaver-extras-base-5.32-4.fc21.x86_64
Feb 05 18:49:32 Updated: 1:xscreensaver-extras-5.32-4.fc21.x86_64
Feb 05 18:49:32 Updated: firewall-config-0.3.13-2.fc21.noarch
Feb 05 18:49:32 Updated: claws-mail-plugins-smime-3.11.1-3.fc21.x86_64
Feb 05 18:49:32 Updated: claws-mail-plugins-vcalendar-3.11.1-3.fc21.x86_64
Feb 05 18:49:32 Updated: claws-mail-plugins-tnef-3.11.1-3.fc21.x86_64
Feb 05 18:49:32 Updated: claws-mail-plugins-newmail-3.11.1-3.fc21.x86_64
Feb 05 18:49:32 Updated: claws-mail-plugins-fetchinfo-3.11.1-3.fc21.x86_64
Feb 05 18:49:33 Updated: claws-mail-plugins-notification-3.11.1-3.fc21.x86_64
Feb 05 18:49:33 Updated: claws-mail-plugins-att-remover-3.11.1-3.fc21.x86_64
Feb 05 18:49:33 Updated: claws-mail-plugins-mailmbox-3.11.1-3.fc21.x86_64
Feb 05 18:49:33 Updated: claws-mail-plugins-rssyl-3.11.1-3.fc21.x86_64
Feb 05 18:49:33 Updated: claws-mail-plugins-attachwarner-3.11.1-3.fc21.x86_64
Feb 05 18:49:33 Updated: claws-mail-plugins-archive-3.11.1-3.fc21.x86_64
Feb 05 18:49:33 Updated: claws-mail-plugins-spam-report-3.11.1-3.fc21.x86_64
Feb 05 18:49:33 Updated: xfdashboard-0.3.8-1.fc21.x86_64
Feb 05 18:49:33 Updated: patch-2.7.4-1.fc21.x86_64
Feb 05 18:49:33 Updated: gparted-0.20.0-1.fc21.x86_64
Feb 05 18:49:33 Updated: tbb-4.3-1.20141204.fc21.x86_64
Feb 05 18:49:41 Updated: google-chrome-stable-40.0.2214.111-1.x86_64
Feb 05 18:49:41 Updated: openal-soft-1.16.0-4.fc21.x86_64
Feb 05 18:49:41 Updated: xorg-x11-drv-synaptics-1.8.1-2.fc21.x86_64
Feb 05 18:49:42 Updated: docker-io-1.4.1-8.fc21.x86_64
Feb 05 18:49:42 Updated: polkit-0.112-7.fc21.1.x86_64
Feb 07 09:22:29 Installed: kernel-core-3.18.5-201.fc21.x86_64
Feb 07 09:22:32 Installed: kernel-modules-3.18.5-201.fc21.x86_64
Feb 07 09:22:32 Installed: ocl-icd-2.0.4-3.git20131001.4ee231e.fc21.x86_64
Feb 07 09:22:33 Updated: ffmpeg-libs-2.4.6-2.fc21.x86_64
Feb 07 09:22:33 Installed: libavdevice-2.4.6-2.fc21.x86_64
Feb 07 09:22:35 Installed: kmod-VirtualBox-3.18.5-201.fc21.x86_64-4.3.20-4.fc21.2.x86_64
Feb 07 09:22:49 Updated: selinux-policy-3.13.1-105.1.fc21.noarch
Feb 07 09:22:49 Updated: kernel-tools-libs-3.18.5-201.fc21.x86_64
Feb 07 09:22:49 Updated: mplayer-common-1.1-32.20150123svn.fc21.x86_64
Feb 07 09:22:49 Updated: mplayer-1.1-32.20150123svn.fc21.x86_64
Feb 07 09:22:49 Updated: kernel-tools-3.18.5-201.fc21.x86_64
Feb 07 09:23:05 Updated: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-105.1.fc21.noarch
Feb 07 09:23:05 Updated: kmod-VirtualBox-4.3.20-4.fc21.2.x86_64
Feb 07 09:23:05 Updated: ffmpeg-2.4.6-2.fc21.x86_64
Feb 07 09:23:05 Installed: kernel-3.18.5-201.fc21.x86_64
Feb 07 09:23:08 Installed: kernel-modules-extra-3.18.5-201.fc21.x86_64
Feb 07 09:23:08 Updated: rubygem-nokogiri-1.6.6.2-1.fc21.x86_64
Feb 07 09:23:23 Installed: kernel-devel-3.18.5-201.fc21.x86_64
Feb 07 09:23:23 Updated: kernel-headers-3.18.5-201.fc21.x86_64
Feb 07 09:23:23 Updated: wkhtmltopdf-0.12.2.1-1.fc21.x86_64
Feb 07 09:23:23 Erased: kmod-VirtualBox-3.17.7-300.fc21.x86_64-4.3.20-2.fc21.2.x86_64
Feb 07 09:23:26 Erased: kmod-acpi_call-3.17.7-300.fc21.x86_64-1.1.0-3.fc21.x86_64
Feb 07 09:23:28 Erased: kmod-tp_smapi-3.17.7-300.fc21.x86_64-0.41-5.fc21.x86_64
Feb 07 09:23:57 Installed: kmod-acpi_call-3.18.5-201.fc21.x86_64-1.1.0-3.fc21.x86_64
Feb 07 09:24:01 Installed: kmod-tp_smapi-3.18.5-201.fc21.x86_64-0.41-5.fc21.x86_64
Feb 09 09:21:36 Updated: postgresql-libs-9.3.6-1.fc21.x86_64
Feb 09 09:21:36 Updated: postgresql-9.3.6-1.fc21.x86_64
Feb 09 09:21:36 Updated: libdrm-2.4.59-4.fc21.x86_64
Feb 09 09:21:36 Updated: libdrm-devel-2.4.59-4.fc21.x86_64
Feb 09 09:21:37 Updated: postgresql-contrib-9.3.6-1.fc21.x86_64
Feb 09 09:21:37 Updated: postgresql-server-9.3.6-1.fc21.x86_64
Feb 09 09:21:37 Updated: 1:lpf-flash-plugin-11.2.202.442-1.fc21.x86_64
Feb 09 09:21:38 Updated: imlib2-1.4.6-3.fc21.x86_64
Feb 09 09:21:38 Updated: libgadu-1.12.1-1.fc21.x86_64
Feb 09 09:21:38 Updated: 1:perl-Digest-SHA-5.95-1.fc21.x86_64
Feb 09 09:21:38 Updated: 2:qemu-guest-agent-2.1.3-1.fc21.x86_64
Feb 09 09:21:39 Updated: 2:gedit-3.14.3-1.fc21.x86_64
Feb 09 09:21:39 Updated: xorg-x11-drv-synaptics-1.8.1-3.fc21.x86_64
Feb 09 09:21:39 Updated: libdrm-2.4.59-4.fc21.i686
```

One of these upgraded packages probably conflicts somehow with docker. I also tried switching to several different kernel versions, e.g. 3.18.5-201.fc21.x86_64, 3.18.3-201.fc21.x86_64 and 3.17.8-300.fc21.x86_64 but the result is the same.

Comment: Could you add the solution as an answer to your own question? Then you can accept it later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was asked to post the solution as an answer, so here it is.

### SOLUTION

Ok, I found out what was the problem - it was my docker config in `/etc/sysconfig/docker` of course. Steps I took to find it out:

- firstly, I renamed `/var/lib/docker/` to allow docker to recreate its files structure (I decided to try it out after reading https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1099375) - this helped `sudo systemctl docker start` to run with no error,
- but before I did that I reinstalled docker, so my previous docker settings were missing - I added them and did restart: it failed,
- I had to remove `-H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376` which seemed to be some settings required only by boot2docker (my companions use b2d on MacOS and Windows),
- I was also asked to add `-s overlay` to run options.

It resolved the problem. It also works with the previous `/var/lib/docker/` directory (at least I don't have to download all containers once again).

[@marekgoldmann](https://twitter.com/marekgoldmann) also pointed me to that issue - https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1186669#c2 and especially its explanation on bugzilla. Thanks Marek for you kind help! :)

I hope that this post might help you if you run into quite similar problems with docker.

Comment: Thanks Szymon, you saved my day! Exact same problem and same solution steps worked pretty well

Comment: That's great you find it useful @Serhat :) Feel free to upvote ;)

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  Just to add, you do need to do the reinstall (I tried without).  Saved me a big panic.